# Atualizar o conteúdo de uma página sem recarregá-la

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estou trabalhando em um projeto para a faculdade onde eu gostaria de atualizar o conteúdo de uma página sem recarregá-la. A página em questão tem seu conteúdo recebido de um script `PHP`, que por sua vez pega o conteúdo em um banco de dados `MySQL`.

Esse é meu script `PHP`:

```
<?php
    include "php/conn.php";

    function lerNotas() {   
        global $conn;
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notas");                

        if (!$query) {
            die('A consulta falhou:' . mysqli_error($conn));
            } else {
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {                
                echo "<div class=\"nota\">";
                echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ids[]\" value=\"" . $linha['id'] . "\"><br>";
                echo "<span class=\"titulo\">". $linha['titulo'] . "</span><br>";
                echo nl2br($linha['conteudo']) . "<br><br>";
                echo "<span class=\"textoPequeno\">Criado em " . $linha['data_criacao'] . "</span><br/>";
                echo "<span class=\"textoPequeno\">Atualizado pela última vez em " . $linha['data_atualizacao'] . "</span>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
    }           

    function apagarNotas() {
        global $conn;
        foreach($_POST['ids'] as $x) {
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM notas WHERE id=".$x );
            if (!$query) {
                die('A consulta falhou:' . mysqli_error($conn));
                } else {                
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

E esse é o conteúdo de minha página:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Notas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./nova_nota.php">Adicionar nota</a></li>
                <li><a href="./ler_notas.php">Listar notas</a></li>
                <li><a href="./exclui_notas.php">Excluir notas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <?php           
                echo lerNotas();            
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="apagar" value="Apagar notas selecionadas" class="buttonEnviar">
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['apagar'])){
                    echo apagarNotas();                 
                }
            ?>
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Repare que o formulário é preenchido por `PHP`/`MySQL`. O que eu gostaria é que, quando eu clicasse no botão, a `query` para apagar fosse executada e o conteúdo da página fosse atualizado sem atualizar a página. Eu até consegui fazer isso na hora de inserir um dado no banco de dados, mas para excluir e atualizar a página estou me batendo.

**Edit:**
Complementando o parágrafo acima, foi assim que eu fiz a inserção de dados sem recarregar a página:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Notas</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/novaNota.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <meta charset="utf8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./nova_nota.php">Adicionar nota</a></li>
                <li><a href="./ler_notas.php">Listar notas</a></li>
                <li><a href="./exclui_notas.php">Excluir notas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="formulario">
            <form id="form" name="form">
                <input id="titulo" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Título" class="inputTexto"><br>
                <textarea id="conteudo" name="conteudo" placeholder="Conteúdo" class="textarea"></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar nota" class="buttonEnviar" id="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Essa é a página, onde tem um link de um script que é responsável por inserir o dado no banco de dados:

**novaNota.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
        var conteudo = $("#conteudo").val();
        if (titulo == '' || conteudo == '') {
            alert("Nenhum campo pode ser deixado em branco!");
            } else {
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.post("php/adicionarNota.php", {
                titulo1: titulo,
                conteudo1: conteudo
                }, function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Que, por sua vez, usa esse script PHP:

**adicionarNota.php**

```
<?php
    include "conn.php";

    define('NOME_TABELA', 'notas');
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo1'];
    $conteudo = $_POST['conteudo1'];
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO " . NOME_TABELA . " (titulo, conteudo, data_criacao, data_atualizacao) VALUES (\"" . $titulo . "\", \"" . $conteudo . "\",\"" . $data . "\", null)");

    if ($query) {
        echo "Nota criada com sucesso!";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Espero que esteja claro e que isso ajude!

Comment: *"Eu até consegui fazer isso na hora de inserir um dado no banco de dados, mas para excluir e atualizar a página estou me batendo."* Poste o teu código até aqui.

Comment: @Andrey, adicionei no post. Espero que dê para entender.

Comment: Olha cara, você pode utilizar Ajax para resolver isso. Aqui tem um exemplo : http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/demo.html#page1 E como fazer: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

Comment: Não sei se esse exemplo realmente me ajuda, pois não pretendo trocar o conteúdo da página por outro, quero apenas atualizá-lo. Acho que o problema é que o conteúdo em si é obtido por PHP...

Comment: Caso você queira pegar apenas os valores sem mexer no resto do conteúdo, se pode usar o jQuery.post();

Comment: @brunodotcom eu preciso alterar o conteúdo, sim. preciso que o `form` seja re-criado. Mas os dados do mesmo vem do PHP.

Comment: Você pode deixar uma pagina em PHP que terá a função de retornar esses dados para você e trazer do jeito que você desejar lá, e com a função post() você retorna as informações dessa página que você criou sem tem que atualizar a página em si. Eu uso muito ela para fazer aqueles combobox que você seleciona o estado e depois a cidade de acordo com o estado selecionado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não hoje não tenho muito tempo para criar o código, mas acho que dever ter conhecimentos para fazer isto:

1) acrescente um id na checkbox:

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ids[]\" value=\"" . $linha['id'] . "\" id='i:$linha['id']'>"
```

2) crie um evento onsubmit como já fez para gravar. Antes guarde o array das checkbox

```
var ch = document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
```

3) faça um função ajax para enviar esses dados para o servidor (função apagarNotas() no arquivo php.

4) Na função php apagarNotas() crie uma resposta que apagou as notas com sucesso:

```
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $x) {
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM notas WHERE id=".$x );
            if (!$query) {
                 $control = false;
                } else {
                 $control =true;
            }
        }

if(!control)
die('A consulta falhou:' . mysqli_error($conn));

return '{"result":"ok"}';
```

5) Se recebeu "OK" pegue nas checbox guardadas em var ch e remova os elementos que embrulham as notas:

```
for (var b=0; ch.length; b++){
  if(ch.checked){ 
      c=document.getElementByID("i:"+ch).parentNode();
      c.parentNode.remove(c)
 }
}
```

Estou a publicar sem verificar o código, mas acho que esta receita server para o que pretende fazer.

Comment: A solução parece perfeita! Vou testar daqui a pouco e volto aqui pra dizer o que deu, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Tudo está bem até ao momento do **SUBMIT** que quando utilizado num **form** é gerido de uma forma muito específica ou seja é um elemento do qual é esperado uma ação "default" e por isso acontece o "reload" ou como  descreves-te...

> fosse executada e o conteúdo da página fosse atualizado sem atualizar
>   a página.

no entanto a acção que é "captada" é o **click** e não a acção de **SUBMIT**... para resolver a minha solução é usar o:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Como referi e para "captar" o **SUBMIT DO FORM** e não o *"click"* a solução é:

no form adiciona um ID:

```
<form id="exemplo">
```

depois no javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#exemplo").submit(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        [o teu código]
    });
});
```